# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

I'm facing a problem when building project having multiDexEnabled is true in build.gradle

here is the error

**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.

> java.io.IOException: Can't read [APP_PATH/app/build/intermediates/transforms/CLASSES/FULL_PROJECT/jarMerging/debug/classes.jar] (Can't process class [i.class] (Unknown verification type [19] in stack map frame))**

here is the my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'



android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    applicationId "com.example.application"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 13
    versionName "2.4"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}


dependencies {
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup:android-times-square:1.6.4@aar'
compile files('libs/IDTUniPaySDK.jar')
compile files('libs/emv-bertlv-0.1.3-shaded.jar')
compile files('libs/audio.jar')
compile files('libs/bluebambooV4.4.jar')
compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.6.2'
compile 'com.google.code.ksoap2-android:ksoap2-android:3.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

when i removed these two dependencies(1-compile files('libs/audio.jar')
2-compile files('libs/bluebambooV4.4.jar')) and also removed the reference code that used these 2 dependencies , my project works fine.

Comment: which version of gradle plugin are you using?

Comment: @gabriele-mariotti com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta3

Comment: Try to use the last com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta6

Comment: @gabriele-mariotti i do and gets same error but  when i removed these two dependencies(1-compile files('libs/audio.jar')
2-compile files('libs/bluebambooV4.4.jar')) and also removed the reference code that used these 2 dependencies , my project works fine.

Comment: I also get this issue often, Try deleting the app/build folder and then try debug again. This sometimes fixes my problem. I dono if there is a bug in gradle or an issue with its temp files.

Comment: same problem, did you solve the problem ? any help ?

Answer (score 1):

This is what i did to fix this issue:

Go to File > project structure and 
 - in section Modules, check for each module, if the **Build tool version** in ***Properties*** is equivalent to the **Target Sdk version** in ***Flavors***.

[Screenshot of the solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pomS2.png) 
log of my error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
> >     java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
> >     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing
> >     java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with
> >     arguments {--dex --num-threads=4 --multi-dex --main-dex-list
> >     ..\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\release\maindexlist.txt --output
> >     ..\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\release\folders\1000\1f\main
> >     ..\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\release\jars\1\1f\combined.jar}